# Problemas con input type submit en Google apps script

Tags: html5, google-apps-script

Hice una webapp con google apps script con un formulario. Recojo los datos al apretar un botón y los guardo del en un google sheets con google.script.run.  Puse un `<input type="submit">` para usar la validación de datos del HTML, pero al apretar el botón me manda a una página en blanco.
Dejo mi código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
      <form>
        <input type="text" required>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
      <script> 
      //aquí recojo los datos y los mando al sheets
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Después de apretar el botón me manda a una página en blanco con esta url: https://n-ofi44rb6rxxmigepxr74wackks6kkcwqyjs524a-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?
Yo solo necesito el submit para validar los datos y no tener que hacer la validación con Javascript. No necesito enviar los datos con el botón, los datos los envío con JS. Quiero permanecer en la misma página después de apretar el botón submit.

Me ayudaría mucho una respuesta, porque estoy aprendiendo y no sé como resolver este problema.

Comment: Te hace falta usar `preventDefault`. En mi respuesta a  https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65908/65, entre otras cosas, se muestra como usarlo

Comment: Otra pregunta -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171072/65 con una respuesta mía mostrando cómo usar `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

En base al comentario de Rubén voy a contestar mi pregunta.
Hay que poner event.preventDefault() como muestro en el código a continuación.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="formulario">
        <input type="text" required>
          <button id="btn">Enviar</button>
      </form>
      <script>  
        formulario.addEventListener('submit', saludar)
        function saludar(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log('Hola mundo!')
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```